# PowerShell script to login to a website

Tags: forms, powershell, authentication, web

I've tried about a dozen suggestions that I've found so far.  I'm able to get a couple websites to work, but, not the one I really need.

This is what I'm using minus the url:

```
$username="myname"
$password="mypass"

$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Visible = $true
$ie.navigate($url)

Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 5000

$ie.Document.getElementByID("uname").value = $username
$ie.Document.getElementByID("adminloginpassword").value = $password
```

I keep getting: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

Below is the info from inspecting the elements.. I'm completely new to PowerShell unfortunately so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<form action="processAdminLogin.sdi" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" name="login" onsubmit="return toggleContinueImage(this)" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="initial_function" value="">
<div class="login-shadow-square" style="width: 450px;">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="8" class="adminLogin">

<tbody><tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;<br></td></tr>

<tr>
<td class="lbl"><label for="uname" class="adminLoginText">Username</label></td>
<td align="left"><input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" value="" size="25" maxlength="25"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="lbl"><label for="adminloginpassword" class="adminLoginText">Password</label></td>
<td align="left"><input type="password" name="adminloginpassword" id="adminloginpassword" size="25" maxlength="25" autocomplete="off"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td class="smaller" align="left"><input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember"><label for="remember" class="adminLoginText">Remember my username on this computer.</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td align="left">
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">document.write("<input type='image' value='Submit' src='//u
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try to use another URL (with other ID for elements)? Did you run PowerShell as admin? Is the URL on the Intranet? Are those 5 seconds enough? Probably it's slower and you need to increase that value.

Comment: Is the inspected element taken from within `$url` or from within a login popup window?

Comment: I went the website and on IE and right-clicked to get Inspect Element.    I've  gotten several other websites working just fine.  Gmail, Facebook, etc.  Just having issues with this site.     It's not an intranet site.  I'll try increasing the wait time or using the $ie.busy as was suggested as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sleeping for five seconds, see if IE is busy and sleep until it isn't. Like so,

```
while($ie.Busy) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 }
```

Also, it would be good practice to check if the object exists before trying to manipulate it. Should it not exist, maybe a reload would be in order.

Comment: I had that the while part in a different version, my bad.  When I used it I got a disconnect error: The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.  Not sure what you mean on checking if it exists?  I'm watching the site come up and I got the object name from the Inspect Element.